# Laravel Echo, get users presence without joining the channel

Tags: laravel-echo, user-presence, laravel-websockets

To display a counter of users connected on each channels i tried :

```
           this.rooms.forEach((el) => {
                Echo.join('room.' + el.id)
                    .here((users) => {
                        el.users_count = users.length;
                    })
                    .joining((user) => {
                        el.users_count++;
                    })
                    .leaving((user) => {
                        el.users_count--;
                    });
            });
```

But since the current user is joining the channel, he's added in the counter, and appears in the room as connected.

Is there a way to access to the channel statistics whithout joining the channel?

I'm using laravel-websockets package and laravel echo.